# How to specify another domain?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have own url. However, I cannot state this url after I have deployed my web site on Windows Azure. WindowsAzure gives me such address with addition: ".azurewebsites.net".

How to state my own address in WindowsAzure? I have own url.

Comment: Google please... This is the first result. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/

Comment: -1 for not using google before coming here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - In your DNS registrar create a CNAME record like following.

Name = awverify.mydomain.com

Value = awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net

TTL = 86400

2 - In Azure panel, add mydomain.com to your custom domains. It should show green check.

3 - Go back to your DNS registrar's web site and add an A Record for your custom domain using to IP provided to you by Microsoft in Azure Portal.

Name = mydomain.com

Value = 64.49.121.33

TTL = 7200

Detailed description can be found [here.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/)